# SBT Scala Assembly Plugin

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly

How to enable Assembly plugin on my repo. https://github.com/rmuhamedgaliev/skala-skeleton i tried fix them. But can't run this with command **sbt assembly**]

> assembly
>   [error] Not a valid command: assembly
>   [error] Not a valid project ID: assembly
>   [error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
>   [error] Not a valid key: assembly
>   [error] assembly
>   [error]         ^
>   exit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing some configuration (which is in details described [here](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly#applying-the-plugin-to-multi-project-buildscala)).

First you have to import `sbtassembly.Plugin._` before importing `AssemblyKeys`.

```
import sbtassembly.Plugin._
import AssemblyKeys._
```

Then you have to add settings to your build (note extra `assemblySettings`):

```
lazy val root = Project(
  "root",
  file("."),
  settings = buildSettings ++ assemblySettings ++ Seq (
    libraryDependencies ++= rootDependencies
  )
)
```